# How to isolate user from network

Tags: networking, internet, users

Just installed Ubuntu 20.04 and like what I see -- almost.

I have set the main Network settings "Make available to other users" as un-checked.
I have created a "Standard" user DAVE.
I open DAVE's Network Settings and there is no connection show -- that's good.
I click the Firefox icon and it loads an Internet page. Say what??

I do not want DAVE to have access to the Internet.

Since "Make avail..." seems to be ignored in the Main User setup, how do I make it work to prevent DAVE surfing?

Thanks

Comment: "Make available to other users"  prevents others from activating up that connection. It doesn't prevent anyone from using said connection if it were already activated by you. You could use `iptables` to deny all traffic from processes running as a certain user.

Comment: Thanks, but I am having trouble making that work as there is no eth0 etc that I can find. Care to elaborate a little?